# Finding the Taylor series about 0 of a function

Tags: taylor-expansion

The function I'm talking about is : $e^\frac{log(1+x)}{x}$ . I can't find a nice closed form for the associated series using just the expansion of $e^x$ . What am I missing here?

How can a simplification be  done ?

Comment: Do you want the full form, or just an approximation up to some order?

Comment: If by full form you mean generalized form, yes, that is what I'm looking for

Comment: How would one integrate about 0? The function isn't even defined at $x=0$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hint: What can you say about $e^{\frac ab}$? or simply $e^{m\times n}$?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind..

Answer (score 0):

$e^{\frac{\log{(1+x)}}{x}}=(e^{\log{(1+x)}})^{\frac{1}{x}}=(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Comment: Well, is this any simpler ? Because applying the binomial theorem on this one doesn't seem safe since $\frac{1}{x}$ is not a constant.